# Accessing app outside kubernetes cluster with minikube

Tags: docker, kubernetes, minikube

i'm new to kubernetes , i'm trying to learn it using minikube and i'm facing a problem with accessing apps outside the cluster. i created a  deployment:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-deployment
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx

  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx:1.7.9
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
```

To access it i need to expose it decoratively or imperatively. In the imperative way it works  :

```
kubectl expose deployment nginx-deployment --port 80 --type NodePort
```

When i create a service declaratively i always end up with a **connection refused error**  :

```
apiVersion: v1

kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nginx
  labels:
    app: nginx
spec:
  type : NodePort
  ports:
  - port : 8080
    nodePort : 30018
    protocol : TCP
  selector:
    app: nginx
```

curl -k http://NodeIP:NodePort returns :

> curl: (7) Failed to connect to Node IP port NodePORT: Connection
>   refused

Comment: Add target port ( https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#defining-a-service) and use port 30018 in your curl command

Comment: i did it and it doesn"t work, and btw " By default and for convenience, the targetPort is set to the same value as the port field."

Comment: Is it possible to update "kubectl describe" output of service and endpoints? Did you configure Nginx to listen on port 8080

Comment: There is no fundamental difference between the imperative and declarative approach in kubernetes. The imperative command boils down to the generation of a specific declarative specification. Try to run `kubectl expose deployment nginx-deployment --port 80 --type NodePort --dry-run -o yaml` and you'll see what I mean. Try to compare this output with your declarative `yaml` specification written by yourself and you should notice the key differences. I can already see a fundamental difference. Most probably if you use `kubectl expose ... --port 8080 ...` it won't work either ;)

Comment: @mario yes indeed but i can"t figure out why ? the port number should match the exact containerPort  am i right  ? so what's the difference in this case scenario ?

Comment: @Elias, please see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Ansil suggested, your **nginx** should be configured to listen on port `8080` if you want to refer to this port in your `Service` definition. By default it listens on port `80`.

You cannot make it listen on different port like `8080` simply by specifying different `containerPort` in your `Deployment` definition as in your example:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-deployment
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx

  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx:1.7.9
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
```

You can easily verify it on your own by attaching to such `Pod`:

```
kubectl exec -ti <nginx-pod-name> -- /bin/bash
```

Once you're there, run:

```
ss -ntlp
```

And you should see on which port your **nginx** actually listens on.

Additionally you may:

```
cat /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
```

It will also tell you on which port your **nginx** is configured to listen. That's all. It's really simple. You changed `containerPort` to `8080` but inside your container nothing actually listens on such port.

You can still expose it as a `Service` (no matter declaratively or imperatively) but it won't change anything as eventually it points to the wrong port on your container, on which nothing listens and you'll see message similar to this one:

```
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 10.1.2.3 port 30080: Connection refused
```

Comment: Yes sir you're right , i was confused . hence we can sepecify the port to match the container and us targetPort to match the port on which the app is running !

Answer (score 0):

Once you create a service in minikube you can expose the service to the outside of the minikube VM (host machine) using the command

`minikube service SERVICE_NAME`

Refer: https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/reference/commands/service/

Comment: yes works like charm , but why i don't have to call it when i create a service with the imperative way ?

Comment: well that service is accessible within the VM ie you can do minikube ssh and do curl, but to access from the host machine you have to explicitly ask for it :)